# canvas - can you set a coordinate as a new zero point to position elements relatively to?

Tags: canvas, positioning

I'm currently working on a little game in order to get familiar with the canvas thingy - now I've got a Menu class like this

```
function Menu(x,y,width,height,...,game){
    this.x      = x;
    this.y      = y;
    this.width  = width;
    this.height = height;
    // ...

    this.render = function(){
        game.stage.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height); // draw background
        // ...
        game.stage.fillText("MENU", this.x + 20, this.y + 10);
    }
}
```

is it possible set the `this.x` and the `this.y` as some kind of default value, so I don't have to write `this.x + ...` every time I want to position something within the menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just translate your scene to the menu position (this.x, this.y) at the begining of menu drawing function. Don't forget to reset it afterwards.

I assume `game.stage` is a canvas context object.

```
game.stage.save();
game.stage.translate(this.x, this.y);

// now (0, 0) becomes (this.x, this.y)
// ... some drawings

game.stage.restore();
```